# RTC DS1307 module not working

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc

I have a problem with an RTC: it doesn't work correctly. When I try to read date or time, I only see the characters "àààààààà" or or the program is blocked.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <RTClib.h>

DS1307 rtc;
DateTime rtcTime;

void setup() {
  //zainicjowanie generatora liczb losowych
  randomSeed(A0); 
  Wire.begin();
  rtc.begin();
}

void loop() {
  rtcTime = rtc.now();
  int mm = rtcTime.minute();
  Serial.println(mm);
  
  delay(500);
}
```

This function blocks my program:

```
String timeRTC(){
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  String Hour = "0" + String(now.hour()); 
  String Minutes = "0" + String(now.minute()); 
  String Seconds = "0" + String(now.second());

  if (Hour.length() == 3) {
    Hour = Hour.substring(1);
  }
  if (Minutes.length() == 3) {
    Minutes = Minutes.substring(1);
  }
  if (Seconds.length() == 3) {
    Seconds = Seconds.substring(1);
  }

  return Hour+":"+Minutes+":"+Seconds;
}
```

I can't find what is causing this problem. I use an Arduino Uno in the WOKWI emulator.

```
String dateRTC(){
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  String Day = "0" + String(now.day()); 
  String Month = "0" + String(now.month()); 
  String Year = String(now.year());

  if (Day.length() == 3) {
    Day = Day.substring(1);
  }
  if (Month.length() == 3) {
    Month = Month.substring(1);
  }

  return Day+"-"+Month+"-"+Year;
}

String timeRTC(){
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  String Hour = "0" + String(now.hour()); 
  String Minutes = "0" + String(now.minute()); 
  String Seconds = "0" + String(now.second());

  if (Hour.length() == 3) {
    Hour = Hour.substring(1);
  }
  if (Minutes.length() == 3) {
    Minutes = Minutes.substring(1);
  }
  if (Seconds.length() == 3) {
    Seconds = Seconds.substring(1);
  }

  return Hour+":"+Minutes+":"+Seconds;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link to your WOKWI project?

Comment: I use free version of WOKWI. This is link for my project: https://file.io/y1XjwyqHjhNk

Comment: The link says “The transfer you requested has been deleted.”

Comment: I shared the file again:  https://easyupload.io/b0e4w8

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked my program"?

Comment: Where is the `Serial.begin()` specifying the used baud rate? And it seems, that the function  `timeRTC()` is not used in your program, so how does it block the program?

Comment: Unresponsive/frozen program.

Comment: I modified it many times trying to solve the problem, hence the shortcomings in the code. I have included two RTC functions in the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a problem with the RTC: if you call `Serial.begin()` in
`setup()`, and remove everything in your `loop()` after
`Serial.println(mm);`, the program works as expected. Your problem is
elsewhere. Most likely you are corrupting memory, which leads to
unpredictable behavior.

Side note: if you switch to Adafruit's RTClib (called simply “RTClib” in
the library manager), you can simplify `timeRTC()` to this:

```cpp
String timeRTC() {
    return rtc.now().timestamp(DateTime::TIMESTAMP_TIME);
}
```